# Emoji are not inserting in database node js mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, utf-8, utf8mb4

Hello I am here to discus one thing. I am building up a web service that makes a goal for inserting emoji data into database field. I am working with Node JS + Mysql.
I set charset to **UTF-8** or **utf8mb4** but this is not solving my problem.
some emoji are inserting perfect { :) }. but some of are converted into square or removed.
Please help me where I am doing wrong thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

please add **charset : 'utf8mb4'** in your mysql connection pool.

e.g.

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'you_ip',
    user : 'user',
    password : 'password',
    database : 'db',
    charset : 'utf8mb4'
});
```

Original Post: https://www.koffeewithkode.com/emoji-are-not-inserting-in-database-node-js-mysql/

Comment: also restart your node server.

Comment: keep doing coding.. :)

Comment: you saved me dude!

Comment: Saved me as well! Can't believe this isn't default behaviour...