# node.js/MySQL: Some string encodings (Emoji) are throwing errors when I try to insert into database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, character-encoding

I've got a node.js script running that pulls data out of a public "database" (it's a 'blockchain') and then performs some operations on it and then inserts it into a MySQL database.  I've got the MySQL database using `UTF8_general_ci` encoding. The vast majority of data parses fine, but every so often it hits something it can't insert.  I get this error:

```
code: 'ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD',
  errno: 1366,
  sqlMessage: 'Incorrect string value: \'\\xF0\\x9F\\x8D\\x95 N...\' for column \'body\' at row 1',
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  index: 0,
```

It shows the bit of string that seems to be causing the error, and it always has this distinct question mark character:

`This looks like Paradise for me! ����\`

I'm guessing this is an encoding issue?  Is there a way I can convert these before it throws an error?  I'm not sure what encoding this blockchain uses, and I'm not even sure how I'd find out.

edit: here's what another example (of the error) shows on the web interface to this blockchain:

> And your very welcome !

another edit:  I should point out that I am using `mysql.format(sql, inserts)` to handle inadvertent sql problems with the data -https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#preparing-queries

Comment: Is there error on the MySQL side or the Node side?

Comment: It shows in the node console. There's a bit more error info that I'll edit in just now.

Comment: Try utf8mb4 (mysql's actual implementation of UTF8)

Comment: I just tried utf8mb4_unicode_ci and it's throwing the same errors.

Comment: I've tried all the non-language specific (and BIN) utf8mb4 encodings in the database now, and none of them avoid that error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The likely answer is that the MySQL connection did not specify `utf8mb4`.  (Specifically, MySQL's `utf8` will *not* suffice for Emoji.)  Can you provide the connection code?  Here is a fallback:  Execute this after connecting to MySQL:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4
```

Another possible answer is that the web server is not treating the page as `UTF-8`.  One way to solve this is with this in the `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

And the column needs to be `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, not `ut8`.

**node.js connection pooling**

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({ ... , charset : 'utf8mb4'});
```

See [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280148/emoji-are-not-inserting-in-database-node-js-mysql)

Comment: The connection is based on the examples in the mysql nodejs docs: 

var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'my_db'
});

I'm not displaying the characters, so I don't need to worry about things on the webserver side.

Comment: But you do have to worry about the "character set" -- The error is complaining that you are trying to stuff a 4-byte Emoji into a `CHARACTER SET utf8` hole in MySQL.  That is limited to the 3-byte subset of `UTF-8`.

Comment: Thanks -- "node.js" was the clue I needed.  See what I added.

Comment: I've made the change to the connection charset and am just running some data through now.  No errors so far!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this by using [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite) from npm.

So basically:

```
const iconv = require("iconv-lite");
var buf = iconv.encode("weird characters", "utf8");
```

Comment: This is making things worse.  To demonstrate, let's see `SELECT HEX(...) FROM ...`.  If you don't see 4-byte chunks beginning with `F0`, it is a mess.  The character you first mentioned should show `F09F8D95`.  If you get `C3B0C5B8C28DE280A2`, you have "double encoding".  `` is hex `F09F918D F09F9295`

Comment: It's literally stopped the error, so I don't see how it can be making things worse.

Comment: Another possibility is that it converted to  `U+1F32A` or `\u1F32A` type "Unicode" encoding.  That is "worse" for anything other than a web page.  Let's see the hex, so I am not guessing.

Comment: The data looks fine in the database tables.  It's not for displaying, only searching.

Comment: Searching is even worse -- You must have _either_ `F09F918D` in both the search string and the data _or_ `\u1F32A` in both.  Else, the tornado will not match.

Comment: I'm only doing searches on english text.