# Encoding issues storing emojis in MySQL: How can I define a character collation in NodeJS using Prisma ORM?

Tags: mysql, node.js, utf-8, character-encoding, prisma

Dear nodejs experts and database gurus,

We face issues with storing emojis and other special characters in our MySQL database. We get an error by Prisma, which is the "ORM" we use:

> **Conversion from collation utf8_general_ci into utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci impossible for parameter**

```
prisma:query INSERT INTO `app`.`show` [...]
PrismaClientUnknownRequestError: Error occurred during query execution:
ConnectorError(ConnectorError { user_facing_error: None, kind: QueryError(Server(ServerError {
   code: 3988,
   message: "Conversion from collation utf8_general_ci into utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci impossible for parameter",
   state: "HY000" })) })
at cb (/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:38695:17) { clientVersion: '3.8.1' }
prisma:query ROLLBACK
```

We tried the following solutions already:

1. Using different collations on the database (db level, table level, field level): `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`, `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, but the goal is to use a set which is most modern like `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`
2. Changing it to utf8 instead of utf8mb4 resulted in an error like `Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x92\\x95'` and is not our goal as we want to be able to store all emojis
3. Dumping, changing all encoding statements in the sql dump and re-importing with parameters. We used a bunch of parameters in hope it will encode it differently like `--default-character-set=utf8mb4` or `--hex-blob`
4. Defining a charset in our backend as we believe that the database is not the issue, but more the input we send to it like the old PHP way we knew `ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8")`, but as we understood Nodejs does not care about the encoding/charset, but maybe there is a way
5. Defining a charset at the MySQL client, but we did not find a way to do so as we use prisma.io and maybe do not have access to the mysql client underhood. Prisma by itself seems to support utf8mb4 as this is in the docs https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/case-sensitivity#database-collation-and-case-sensitivity and we found a recent discussion about defining it on a more granular level here https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/4743

Maybe two more valuable insights:

- The data comes from a React Native app, but before the database migration, we had no issues, so we hope it is not a problem on the client-side, but for sure, we can specify something there as well, eg. setting HEADER information on the API call, which we do with `axios`
- Before we used the db-as-a-service tool `Airtable`, which was quite a hassle to "break free" from them. We exported everything in CSV format and imported it in a local MySQL db powered with `XAMPP` (which had different options for encoding) and then imported the dump to our new MySQL cluster

Our goal is to

- Set the right encoding character set in our new MySQL cluster
- Send the data in the right format to the DB (setting the same set in NodeJS and React)

Hope you can help us! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`\\xF0\\x9F\\x92\\x95` () needs the `CHARACTER SET` `utf8mb4`, not `utf8`.  The `COLLATION` is irrelevant, other than that it must be consistent (that is, `utf8mb4_...`).  (Note the **4** byte hex, and the **4** in utf8mb4.)

There are several places to specify the charset.  It sounds like you missed a place.

I don't have any notes on Prisma or React, but for node.js:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({ ... , charset : 'utf8mb4'});
```

See [Emoji are not inserting in database node js mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280148/emoji-are-not-inserting-in-database-node-js-mysql)

That's the connection; the table also needs it.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can check that the column has the charset specified or, if not, then the table has the appropriate default.

Yes, the `COLLATION` `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` is probably best for MySQL 8.0.  (It is not available in older versions of MySQL nor in any version of MariaDB.)

Note:  Specifying just a `COLLATION` causes the `CHARACTER SET` to be set to the beginning part of the collation.

PHP's `ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8")` should be fine, but is probably not relevant to the problem).

Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`  The `_client`, `_connection` and `_results` should all be `utf8mb4`.

Character set refers to 'encoding', as in what the bits represent.  Collation deals with comparisons and sorting -- "A" < "a" or not, plus many other variants on that.

Comment: Thanks Rick! I investigated a bit more and it seems to be a prisma.io issue. I am not able to pass the argument `?charset=UTF8MB4` to prisma/mysql client. I tried `SQL_PRISMA_URL='mysql://user:pass@host:port/db?charset=UTF8MB4&sslmode=require&sslcert=ssl.crt&sslaccept=accept_invalid_certs'` but it ignores the charset argument. This is the docs about how to pass arguments to the underlying mysql connection: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mysql#connection-details

Comment: `await prisma.$queryRaw(SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%')`
still returns

'character_set_client': 'utf8mb3', 'character_set_connection': 'utf8mb3', 'character_set_database': 'utf8mb4', 'character_set_results': 'utf8mb3', 'character_set_server': 'utf8mb4', 'character_set_system': 'utf8mb3'

Comment: charset : 'utf8mb4' this part saves my day

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. I could solve it for the current connection by running the query `SET NAMES utf8mb4` - but this doesn't solve it for the connection bool Prisma uses.
I'm currently experimenting with running `SET NAMES utf8mb4` via `init_connect` which is applied to all new connections to mysql. It does seem to work but feels a bit like a workaround instead of a solution. Still not sure what causes prisma to use the "wrong" encoding.

Comment: I did pretty much the same, added this command before start the server: `await prisma.$executeRaw`SET NAMES latin1;``

Comment: @MarcoArruda you need to apply it to all connections, I think your command only applies it to the current connection.