# Set encoding character set to utf8mb4 in Node.js or MySQL client?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, utf-8, character-encoding

When we want to store a string with emojis to our MySQL database, we get this error:

> Conversion from collation utf8_general_ci into utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci impossible for parameter

Can someone explain to me why Node is sending it as `utf8` to MySQL and how I can declare that we have an `utf8mb4` collation? I tried several different encodings on the database side, but I think it is a Node.js or driver configuration that is missing.

The backend is based on Express.js, running on a Debian system within an lts-alpine docker container and the request is sent by a React Native app.

Thx, Florian

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Node.js. The problem is probably that your connections use a different character set than the database. You should configure your DB connections to use utf8mb4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71034035/encoding-issues-storing-emojis-in-mysql-how-can-i-define-a-character-collation/71054524?r=SearchResults&s=1|14.7148#71054524

Comment: Thanks! You are right, the client uses utf8 instead of utf8mb4 as I get `'character_set_connection': 'utf8mb3'` when I query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%'`. It seems to be a prisma.io issue as I am not able to pass the argument `?charset=UTF8MB4` to the prisma-mysql client. This is the docs about passing arguments, but it somehow does not work ... https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mysql#connection-details

Answer (score 0):

You can add character set when creating MySQL client

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
require('dotenv').config();

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.host,
  user: process.env.user,
  port: process.env.port,
  password: process.env.password,
  database: process.env.database,
   charset: 'utf8mb4',
});
```